# how to get attached file url for current post?

Tags: php, urls, attachments

Trying to get the attachment file url for current post, using this code:

```
if ( is_singular('post') ) {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID );
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
          echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); 
        }
    }
    else {
}
    }
```

the problem is:
this code displays the url of a file attached to another post 'author' which is a child post in relationship by ACF advanced custom fields plugin.
I need to display the url of the file attached to current post and not to the child one.
any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try get_pages with

```
'child_of' => get_the_ID(),
'parent' => get_the_ID(),
```

If you need i can post full code

EDIT :

```
if ( is_singular('post') ) {
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_status' => null, 
        'parent' => $post->ID ,
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'sort_order' => 'desc'
    );
    $attachments = get_pages( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); 
        }
    }else {
    }
}
```

I hope this code help you

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. yes please if you can write the full code.

Comment: I already edit my post and write full code ..

Comment: this displays all the urls of all the files attached to the parent and the child posts. is there any way to display only those of parent post?

Comment: So soory , this's my mistake .. I use get_posts not get_pages.. try now with my edit  get_pages

Comment: now nothing is displayed :(

Comment: According to last comment of this [link] (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_pages-how-to-disable-grandchildren) .. you must use sort order too... So add sort_order=>'desc' to $args and try again

Comment: thanks @Kika your answers helped me figure out the solution

Comment: @KhaledSadek works for me only with get_posts, not with get_pages (the attachment is PDF file)

Comment: @Fanky Actually this reply for more than 7 years ago. and I didn't follow the Wordpress updates and changes.
Sorry but you can create a new question and let some one helps you.